# IE. Document.items.all does not work hta

Tags: forms, vbscript, hta, autofill

I am making a tool for work that generates a new project item on our sharepoint.
On the sharepoint we have a form that needs to be filled in and to identify the textfields of the form I use the  `IE.Document.All.Item("id").value=value` command.

It works in a separate vbs file, but when I try to launch it from hta it blocks at the `IE.Documents.All.item` command. Does anybody knows how to solve this?

The code looks like the following (language: vbscript):

```
Sub SendProjectData
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
   set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
   IE.Navigate "https://sharepointpage" 
   IE.Visible = true
   sleep1 6000 'external defined sleep command'

   IE.Document.All.Item("projectid").Value = "projectname" 
   WshShell.AppActivate "IE" 
   WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, I work with:

```
oIe.document.getElementById("testMsgBox").value = "hallo"
```

or

```
oIE.document.all.testMsgBox.value = "hallo"
```

Perhaps that helps, Reinhard

Comment: Hi Reinhard, thank you for the reply. However, it doesn't seem to work as it still prompts the error: "unspecified error". Maybe it is the ".document.", perhaps it is not defined for vbscript when using hta

Comment: I'm just be stumped. Is the text field inside the hta? Then you can access the element with just their ID or name, so 'projectid.Value = "projectname"' should work. Or is the textfield in an other html file and you want to fill it from a hta file using vbs code?

Comment: Hi ReFran, the textfield is in a third party website and I try to fill it with the input from my own local hta. I worked around it by saving my input in a txt file and run the vbs that fills in the textfields (now by parsing the text file) on the website outside of the hta environment

Comment: I solved it by copy pasting the script in a separate vbs file. When I run the file from hta with shell. IE.Document.All.Item() works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Tested under Win10 with IE11:

First the HTML test file:

```
<html>
    <head><title>MyInputFile</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>IE with Input field</h1>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Default text" size="20">
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the HTA file to fill out the html File:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hypertext-Application Demo</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA">
<script language="vbscript">
    sub Window_Onload
        self.resizeto 500,200
        self.MoveTo 50,50
    End Sub

    Sub fillHta()
        myText.value = "New Text"
    End Sub

    Sub startAndFill()
        set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        'Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set oIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
        oIE.Navigate "d:\MyInputFile.html"
        oIE.Visible = true
        Do: Loop Until oIE.Busy = False
        Do: Loop Until oIE.Document.ReadyState = "complete"

        oIe.document.getElementById("myText").value = "New Text" 'use this
        x = oIe.document.getElementById("myText").value
        oIE.document.all.myText.value = x & "; New Text2" 'or this
    End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#99CCFF">
<p>Simple Demo of Hypertext Applikationen</p>
<input type="button" value="Fill HTA input field" onclick="fillHta()">
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Default text" size="20">
<p><input type="button" value="start and fill IE field" onclick="startAndFill()"> D:\MyInputFile.html</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Enjoy, Reinhard